# Github Access Error - AggregateException encountered

Tags: git, github, deployment

I am using a github Repo for almost one year and since this morning I am not able to push my code to the remote repo. I get following error in the command line:

> fatal:  AggregateException encountered. Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.

The credentials.log contains following error:

```
System.AggregateException: Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Fehler beim Senden der Anforderung. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Es konnte kein geschützter SSL/TLS-Kanal erstellt werden..
```

Apparently, yesterday were some releases. See here for more information: https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-02-01-weak-crypto-removal-notice/

Maybe, this could be the reason, but I don't know how to solve it.  Can you help me please? I use Windows 10.

Comment: seems to be the same origin cause..thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to update git. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/57): The last comment from Whoisj. I had the same problem in the morning. It's easy: just download and install git again. See for example [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/installing-and-upgrading-git-776640906.html)

Comment: Thanks, Christoph :) You saved my day

Comment: Was having the same problem, thanks @Christoph!

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me

Comment: Thanks, that would explain why it worked inside a docker image but not inside my working machine. I had also along ' Permission denied (publickey)' error but within a docker I was able to supply a github token, whereas in the working machine with the old git version it was not possible to supply.