# failed to clone repository on github

Tags: github

Hello i am pretty new to using git.I have opened a repository in github and commited to it some files now when i am trying to clone the project on a new pc it gives me an error and i am have a tough time solving so if someone can help me i will thank him.

> Git failed with a fatal error.
>   fatal: AggregateException encountered.
>      One or more errors occurred.
>   error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
>   fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947079/5784831)

Answer (score 0):

Use command

```
git clone "https://username:password@github.com/bsmahala/repo"
```

use your username and password